# selinium and excel poi program

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

i have tried an automation program using selinium and java excel.  Unfortunately formulas to excel is not populating.  I tried using various methods but the intial selinium program is itself terminating with giving only one line in the excel output.  Can some one help.

Comment: Help how? We need to see what you did to tell you what to correct...

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/test/tes123.xls");
        Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis); 
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        FormulaEvaluator evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

        // suppose your formula is in B2
        CellReference cellReference = new CellReference("B2"); 
        Row row = sheet.getRow(cellReference.getRow());
        Cell cell = row.getCell(cellReference.getCol()); 

        if (cell!=null) {
            switch (evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell)) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                    System.out.println(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
                    System.out.println(cell.getErrorCellValue());
                    break;

                // CELL_TYPE_FORMULA will never occur
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA: 
                    break;
            }
        }
```